# How to catch zero scroll?

Tags: javascript

I need to execute some function when an attempt to scroll was made, but no actual scroll happenned. For example, when a page is scrolled to the top and user tries to scroll up, or when a page is scrolled to the possible bottom and user tries to scroll down.

Is there a way to catch that kind of scrolls?

*onscroll* event didn't help

UPD: As people suggest, the only way to catch all scroll attempts is to watch all events from actions that can affect scroll position. As far as i can understand, there are all the ways to scroll: mouse wheel, mouse wheel pressed, keyboard (arrows, numpad arrows, space, page up/down, home, end), touch.

*Actually, this makes me wanna ask another question like "What ways to scroll exist?", should i?*

For example, i want to catch down zero scroll attempts (*is this expression correct in english? A scroll attempt that is happenned when a page is scrolled to the bottom but user tries to scroll it down anyway*). I use scroll event to decide if user scrolled to the bottom and set/unset *finally_scrolled_to_the_bottom* boolean flag.

Next:

1. Touch: If the flag is set, in the touch listener i should check the direction, and if the direction is 'down', fire my function,
2. Keyboard: the same, check if (key is downarrow/numdownarrow/space/pagedown/end && flag is set), if yes - fire my function,
3. Mouse wheel rolls: check if (direction is 'down' && flag is set), if yes - fire function,
4. Mouse wheel presses: ???

Is this all the possible ways to scroll? How to deal with scroll that made with pressed mouse wheel?

Comment: Do you require any and all possible ways of scrolling to be detected? Or are you just interested in the mousewheel? Do you care about up/down arrows for trying to scroll?

Comment: @EdmundReed, yeah, that's the point: to catch all scroll attemps, regardless of way - mouse, keyboard, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) events. Depending on your device, scrolling attempts could also be made by [swiping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), [arrow keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) or anything else.

> I want to catch down zero scroll attempts

I don't think you really can. A good workaround I can imagine would be to prevent the content from ever being scrolled down all the way to the bottom - inside your `onscroll` handler, just reset it to at least 1px above the bottom. The user would always be able to scroll down (and you'd always get a `scroll` event from the scroll-down "attempt") but probably not notice that there is 1px left.

Comment: So, practically, your advice is to watch events of all actions that can affect scroll position?)

Comment: Yes. There is no actual scroll happening, what you want to catch are *scrolling attempts*. There's no event for that, so the best you can do is to watch for the actions that could trigger a scroll.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onwheel` works for me:

```
var foo =  function () {
  console.log(new Date());
}

window.onwheel = foo;
```

gives me new information in the console even when I reach the top of the page.

As @bergi pointed out, onmousewheel is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel), but onwheel works as a direct replacement.

Comment: Notice that `mousewheel` is deprecated